# How can I create nested tree in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, nested-loops

Following the array object data:
Using Javascript data structures, how could I iterate over array object into children array's, every time when I get new children using its ID and parent ID.

Trying to find Parent Id and child nested root nodes using javascript but I couldn't able find, how to iterate array object into its children array. can anyone help me out.

````
var data = [ 
  { id: 7, label: 'a', parentId: 2, childerns: [] },
  { id: 7, label: 'm', parentId: 2, childerns: [] },
  { id: 2, label: 'b', parentId: 5, childerns: [] },
  { id: 5, label: 'c', parentId: 20, childerns: [] },
  { id: 20, label: 'x', parentId: null, childerns: [] },
  { id: 8, label: 'd', parentId: 7, childerns: [] },
  { id: 9, label: 'n', parentId: 8, childerns: [] },
  { id: 9, label: 'n', parentId: 8, childerns: [] } ];```

and looking for the following nested tree pattern:

```var data = [
    {
        id: 20,
        label: 'x',
        parentId: null,
        childerns: [
            {
                id: 5,
                label: 'c',
                parentId: 20,
                childerns: [{
                    id: 2,
                    label: 'b',
                    parentId: 5,
                    childerns: [
                        {
                            id: 7, 
                            label: 'm',
                            parentId: 2,
                            childerns: [] 
                        },
                        {
                            id: 7,
                            label: 'a',
                            parentId: 2,
                            childerns: [{
                                id: 8,
                                label: 'd',
                                parentId: 7,
                                childerns: [
                                    {
                                        id: 9,
                                        label: 'n',
                                        parentId: 8,
                                        childerns: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        id: 9,
                                        label: 'n',
                                        parentId: 8,
                                        childerns: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }]
                        }]
                }]
            }]
    }];```
````

Answer (score 3):

I like the following pattern. First, you use an object to track where in the original array each element lives. Then, you iterate through the original array, adding a reference to the current element to its parent array. If `parentId` is null, add the element to `roots`. After all this, your `roots` array will contain the full tree.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 7, label: 'm', parentId: 2, childerns: [] },
  { id: 2, label: 'b', parentId: 5, childerns: [] },
  { id: 5, label: 'c', parentId: 20, childerns: [] },
  { id: 20, label: 'x', parentId: null, childerns: [] },
  { id: 8, label: 'd', parentId: 7, childerns: [] },
  { id: 9, label: 'n', parentId: 8, childerns: [] },
  { id: 10, label: 'n', parentId: 8, childerns: [] } 
];

// Map element ID to arr index
const arrMap = arr.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
  acc[el.id] = i;
  return acc;
}, {});

const roots = [];

// Push each element to parent's children array
arr.forEach(el => {
  if (el.parentId === null) {
    roots.push(el);
  } else {
    arr[arrMap[el.parentId]].childerns.push(el);
  }
});

console.log(roots);
```

Comment: You're missing duplicate array object which was retrun twice as same. like ```{ id: 7, label: 'a', parentId: 2, childerns: [] },
  { id: 7, label: 'm', parentId: 2, childerns: [] },```

Comment: I assumed that was a mistake. What should happen when there's a duplicate array object?

Comment: Everything should be taken and create a nested array.

Comment: So if there are two parents with the same ID, where do the children go? In your example tree, why is ID 8 only under one of the ID 7 nodes and not under the other?

Comment: whichever duplicate comes last, we can assign one to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a pattern where the children can expand almost infinitely, you should use a class or a constructor, so you can just pass another instance within, as demonstrated in the following `UnitInstance.addChild` method.

```js
 /* constructor */
function Unit(id, label, children){
  this.id = id; this.label = label; this.parentId = null; this.children = [];
  var t = this;
  this.addChild = function(unitInstance){
    unitInstance.parentId = this.id; this.children.push(unitInstance);
    return this;
  }
  if(children){
    children.forEach(function(o){
      t.addChild(o);
    });
  }
  this.getData = function(){
    var c = [];
    this.children.forEach(function(o){
      c.push(o.getData());
    });
    return {id:t.id, label:t.label, parentId:t.parentId, children:c};
  }
}
var x = new Unit(20, 'x'), c = new Unit(5, 'c'), b = new Unit(2, 'b'), m = new Unit(7, 'm'); a = new Unit(7, 'a'), d = new Unit(8, 'd'), n = new Unit(9, 'n');
x.addChild(c.addChild(b.addChild(m.addChild(a.addChild(d.addChild(n).addChild(n))))));
var data = [x.getData()];
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I can't hard code to nest every time when I receive new data

Comment: Every time you receive new data, create a new Unit, which you can just push `UnitInstance.getData()` onto your data Array.

Comment: Not if you do it on an Event, then it's dynamic.